# hash key to bucket instance

Tags: algorithm, hash

What algorithm yields the best distribution when it comes to mapping `hash key --> bucket instance` ?

In other words, let's say I have an hashing function (probably SHA-1) and I have `n` buckets; what algorithm do I use to map a key to a bucket?  E.g. lower bits, upper bits, something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you just `mod` your hash value with the number of buckets. In the unlikely event that the number of buckets is a power of two, you can use bitwise-and instead.

An excerpt from Wikipedia on [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function):

> A common solution is to compute a fixed hash function with a very
>   large range (say, 0 to 2<sup>32</sup> − 1), divide the result by n, and use the
>   division's remainder. If n is itself a power of 2, this can be done by
>   bit masking and bit shifting. When this approach is used, the hash
>   function must be chosen so that the result has fairly uniform
>   distribution between 0 and n−1, for any n that may occur in the
>   application. Depending on the function, the remainder may be uniform
>   only for certain n, e.g. odd or prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

SHA-1 and other [cryptographic hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) should already give you a pretty even distribution tend to behave like a random function (that generates all outputs with equal probability).

So just select the appropriate number of bits from the output of the function to give you a number in the desired range.

You should study the literature on hash functions and hash tables to better understand the space so you can make an informed choice based on your requirements.  You can start from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) or an algorithms text book such as [CLR](http://mitpress.mit.edu/algorithms/). Eventually you'll want to move on to [Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming).